# Once again, Is Silverlight 4 Enterprise ready?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, enterprise

Does Microsoft use or plan to use Silverlight in its own web applications like MS CRM? Is there any known risk for Silverlight LOB applications instead of ASP.NET? Silverlight 4 still does not has wsHttpBinding. Is this a stupid question?

Answer (score 2):

Not a stupid question, but you do have to remember that the cost of rewriting an application (any application, for any reason) is very expensive.

Yes, I think Silverlight 3 and 4 are enterprise-ready. There's still a learning curve, especially with services and managing performance for large applications that may need dynamic loading. But Silverlight has arrived, and I think you'll see more and more of it.

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight 4 finally has most of the stuff that I'd be looking for in an enterprise application.  You can print (at last!), you've got decent data and web service access, and the tools (VS2010 and Expression Blend 4) are more-or-less in place.  Managing and troubleshooting your data bindings is a little easier (though not nearly as easy as it should be).

That said, you still have to choose between WPF on the one hand, and ASP.NET/MVC on the other, with Silverlight being a sort of middle ground.  Unless there was a specific reason to do it otherwise, for most enterprise applications, Silverlight would be my choice.  Creating a great UI with JavaScript/HTML/Ajax is still harder than C#/Silverlight, and WPF doesn't generally offer anything that you can't get with Silverlight and a little bit of cleverness.

Comment: I still have a little worry about lake of wsHttpBinding in sliverlight

Comment: @Nima - I agree with you regarding wsHttpBinding, but honestly the SOAP libraries available for Flash/Flex are pretty painful (they're buggy, slow, and incomplete), so you really don't have another major RIA toolkit as an option. A nice option you might consider with Silverlight is the new .NET RIA Services: http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/

Comment: For an enterprise app, is there any reason to use the wsHttpBinding instead of Net.TCP?  Net.TCP is dramatically faster, and in an enterprise environment you wouldn't normally have the security and access issues that might cause you to drop back to one of the Http* bindings.

Comment: It's not a intranet application, Web access is essential.

Comment: You can still use Net.TCP over the Internet, of course: it's going to be blocked by firewalls in a very small percentage of cases.  Is your concern that you may need to access *other* services (that you don't control)?  If so, the best option might be to access them from the server, rather than from the client.  But you're right: that's a bit of a workaround.

Comment: Main issue with Silverlight 4 is that it leaks like a sieve.  Also memory profiling API has just become available with Silverlight 4, which means that usable profilers are just coming online now.

Comment: It's certainly possible to *write* Silverlight applications that leak like a sieve.  I've done that plenty myself.  But I haven't yet run into situations where it became evident that the Silverlight runtime itself was leaking: the significant leaks have always been in my own code.  And more to the point, I'm having a hard time imagining a situation where a memory leak in the Silverlight runtime was the most significant problem in my application.  There are lots of problems with Silverlight, but memory leaks (IMO) are a long ways from being the most important.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft are working on controls for dynamics http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mscrm4/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=203

They're building the UK NHS CUI with it:
http://www.mscui.net/Showcase/Showcase.aspx

And it's the core runtime for Windows Phone 7, so I figure it's Enterprise ready ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why does Silverlight make sense?  (rhetorical question)

If intranet, then just use WPF  - the old arguments of deployment issues don't really stand with .net 4.0 ?

If internet, then you'd not use it - using a plug-in just makes no sense anymore - use asp.net in that case... you don't really want users - especially coming to a LOB site to run away because they have to install a new plugin - too risky!

I'm not sold on Silverlight - it's a subset of the framework and outside of a smaller .net install really doesn't provide what users want.  Why not get the whole thing vs. a subset?

ie. users on the web are used to a certain web behavior - and Silverlight feels more like a glitzy plugin than a true web application.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft is also working on the [Enterprise Library for Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/agile/archive/2010/10/08/enterprise-library-integration-pack-for-silverlight-what-do-you-want-to-see-in-it.aspx) to support LOB developers.

The backlog is available for public commenting and voting here: http://entlibsl.mswish.net